# Why does Pry format these return values differently?

Tags: ruby, location, proc

In the first statement below, Pry returns a normal-looking object.

In the second, Pry specifies a lambda in the object, but also adds `@(pry)` with a reference to the line inside the Pry session (`:37`). Why doesn't the first return value contain `@(pry)`? Or, conversely, why does the second return value contain it?

```
{}.to_proc
# => #<Proc:0x9b3fed0>

lambda {}
# => #<Proc:0x97db9c4@(pry):37 (lambda)>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second example is a literal, and the proc (lambda) is created there within Ruby code, where it gets the source location.

In the first example, the proc is created by executing a C method (`to_proc`). C code is compiled into Ruby interpreter, which becomes binary code, and it does not make sense to describe the C location in place of a Ruby source location. In fact, you will also not get the source location for the method (which is not the same as the "source location" of the proc it generates, but should be close to it, if they were to be given):

```
{}.method(:to_proc).source_location # => nil
```

However, if the source is written as part of Ruby code, you get the source location:

```
irb(main):001:0> def to_proc
irb(main):002:1>   Proc.new{}
irb(main):003:1> end
=> :to_proc
irb(main):004:0> {}.to_proc
=> #<Proc:0x007f387602af70@(irb):2>
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have anything to do with Pry. This is what you get when you call `inspect` on these two Procs.

I'm not 100% sure, but I have a theory. In the second example, you're passing a block to `lambda`. Although you don't have any code inside the block, you ordinarily would, and when debugging (which is what `inspect` is ordinarily used for) line numbers are important.

In the first example, though, there's no block. You're calling `Hash#to_proc` on an empty Hash (which is irrelevant; you get the same result with `Symbol#to_proc` etc.), and so there's no code to associate a line number with; a line number wouldn't even really make sense.

You can see where this happens in the `proc_to_s` function in [`proc.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/7935edc6aeacbf7cec5b43e16e8c08be754a2387/proc.c#L1149), by the way.